# How to find a primitive root modulo $5^{10}$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, primitive-roots

I know how to find primitive roots of relatively small primes. But how can one possibly find a primitive root modulo $5^{10}$? I can't test every single number less than $5^{10}$. Is there a fast way to locate just one primitive root of $5^{10}$?

Comment: [It’s $2$ or $3$ $\bmod 5$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170648/prove-that-any-primitive-root-r-of-pn-is-also-a-primitive-root-of-p)

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimitiveRoot.html

Answer (score 5):

1. Find a primitive root mod $5$. I notice $3$ is a primitive root mod $5$.
2. Either $3$ or $3 + 5 = 8$ will be a primitive root mod $25$. A quick check shows that $3$ is still a primitive root mod $25$.
3. A primitive root mod $25$ will be a primitive root mod $5^k$ for all $k \geq 1$.

This works because of a few fundamental ideas concerning primitive roots.

> **Lemma**: If $g$ is a primitive root mod an odd prime $p$, then either $g$ or $g + p$ is a primitive root mod $p^2$.
>
> *Proof:* This is the theorem in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/327961/9754), although the phrasing is a little bit different.

And also,

> **Lemma**: If $g$ is a primitive root mod $p^2$ where $p$ is an odd prime, then $g$ is a primitive root mod $p^k$ for all $k \geq 1$.
>
> *Proof:* See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/31679/9754) and its answers.

Comment: $2$ is also a primitive root mod $5$. A bit smaller.